# Dynamics 365 Create email with table data as excel attachment in SSIS

Tags: ssis, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I am not much savvy with SSIS and i have a requirement to send data in a table as Excel attachment to an email in Dynamics 365. I can leverage Kingswaysoft for this. Can i ask for ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can use our [Premium Excel components](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/solutions/ssis-premium-data-flow-components/premium-excel-components) to write to an Excel file and then upload it as an attachment to Dynamics 365. You can reference our blog post, [Extracting CRM Attachments with Ease](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2017/03/21/Extracting-CRM-Attachments-with-Ease), as an example.

Beyond that, if you have specific questions, you can reach out to [our Support team](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us). We are always happy to help.